# Combine const Object with Object retrieved from database in json response

Tags: json, express

I have some relatively static 'config' type data (`meta`) that makes sense to keep in memory, and other more mutable/user-specific data that makes sense to keep in the database (in this case, MongoDB). What I'd like to do is send a `res.json()` that combines the `meta` const with the Object retrieved from the database, but I'm having trouble with the syntax and I don't even know if what I'm trying to do is achievable.

Below are a few attempts to code this:

`users_controller.js`

```
const meta = {
    auth: {label: 'Authentication', depth: 5, hidden: false },
    name: {label: 'Name', depth: 5, hidden: false },
    email: {label: 'Email', depth: 5, hidden: false },
    phone: {label: 'Phone', depth: 5, hidden: false },
    address: {label: 'Address', depth: 5, hidden: false },
    company: {label: 'Company/Organizations', depth: 5, hidden: false },
    member: {label: 'Membership', depth: 5, hidden: false },
}

. . .
. . .

// This is my original code, which works (before trying to add in the "meta" constant):

exports.users_list = function(req,res, next) {
    UserObj.find({},(err,docs)=>res.json(docs));
};

// Below are three attempts to modify the code to add in the "meta" constant

//Syntax 1 (doesn't work):
exports.users_list = function(req,res, next) {
    UserObj.find({},(err,docs)=>res.json(JSON.parse(`'{meta: ${meta}, payload: ${docs}}'`)));
};

//Syntax 2 (doesn't work):
exports.users_list = function(req,res, next) {
    UserObj.find({},(err,docs)=>res.json(JSON.parse(`'{"meta": ${meta}, "payload": ${docs}}'`)));
};

//Syntax 3 (doesn't work):
exports.users_list = function(req,res, next) {
    UserObj.find({},(err,docs)=>res.json(JSON.parse('{"meta":' + meta + ', "payload":' + docs + '}')));
};
```

Many thanks in advance if anyone can help me find the right syntax to "add" in the `meta` constant into the response.

Comment: Oops. I had an extra "}" before `, "payload"`. . . After removing that, it looks like the 4th syntax might work. I'm investigating that now . . .

Answer (score 0):

This works:

`exports.users_list = function(req,res, next) {
    UserObj.find({},(err,docs)=>res.json(JSON.parse('{"meta":' + JSON.stringify(meta) + ', "payload":' + JSON.stringify(docs) + '}')))`